# Inno Setup: Write Registry section under unistall

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I hope you can help me. I don't find a answer her for me as rookie.

I create an Setup for installing drivers and software.

After the `[RUN]` section I need to set registry entries under

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

In this registry I find my installed software under GUIIDs.

Example:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{D1A4DEBD-C2EE-449f-B9FB-E8409F9A0BC5}
```

Now I have set the section `[Registry]` in Inno Setup with following entry:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{D1A4DEBD-C2EE-449f-B9FB-E8409F9A0BC5}\HOTKEYPACK4"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "NoModify"; ValueData: "1"; Components: util
```

My problem is this under subkey:

```
{D1A4DEBD-C2EE-449f-B9FB-E8409F9A0BC5}
```

Compiling the script I get a compile error:

```
Unknown constant
D1A4DEBD-C2EE-449f-B9FB-E8409F9A0BC5

Use two consecutive "{" characters if you are trying to embed a single "{" and not a constant.
```

I don't understand it and if I set `"{"` it doesn't work.

What can I do to make it work ???
Is it better I do this over `[Code]` section ?

Thanks a lot for your help, and I hope you can help me.

Comment: Use **two** consecutive "{" characters. That is `...\{{D1A4DEBD-C2EE-449f-B9FB-E8409F9A0BC5}\...`.

Comment: Omg. Now I understand that with your example. You my hero. Thanks thank thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, this happens because Inno Setup scripting uses constants enclosed in curly braces (like e.g. `{app}`), and you'll just confuse compiler when you write e.g. `{123}` because it's not a built-in constant that would compiler recognize. Hence it asks you to write `{{123}`.

Comment: Yes I have understood that you should do this `"{"` and not `{{`. Crazy be sure I must improve my english. :-)

Comment: Hi TLama or other helper, now I have change it but doesn´t work. After  "RUN" section dont set registry entries. Can you help me please ? need "Code" section ? This is under [Registry] section :   `Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{D1A4DEBD-C2EE-449f-B9FB-E8409F9A0BC5}\HOTKEYPACK4"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "NoModify"; ValueData: "1"; Flags: deletevalue; Components: Util`

Comment: If you are having a 64-bit OS, opening 64-bit regedit (which is the default one), and running a 32-bit mode Inno Setup installer, then you need to look under the node displayed by regedit as `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\...` (there is the `Wow6432Node` pseudo-node after `Software`. The thing is, that 64-bit regedit shows 32-bit registry keys under the `Wow6432Node` tree node (but do not ever access it from your script, that would be wrong). So your script might correctly save the values to 32-bit registry, just your verification might have been wrong.

Comment: Hi TLama, thanks for your answer. No it is 32bit. My setup is only for windows 7 32bit system. I want install utilities and after it is installed I want set in registry the values that users cant uninstall the utility.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of help. Because all that I know is that you changed something (what have you changed ?) and suddenly something happens after `[Run]` section (what happens, what should have happen instead ?). So naturally as first (and at this time last) thing that came to my mind, was that you are looking at the 64-bit regedit. Something tells me that you are looking for the [`installation order`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder) where you would find that `[Run]` section is processed after `[Registry]`, so if you are going to execute an application...

Comment: ...in the `[Run]` section and to this action is related some `[Registry]` entry, you're out of luck, because `[Registry]` section had been processed. But you can still do all this from the `[Code]` section (execute the app. and modify registry), or write e.g. [`AfterInstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall&anchor=AfterInstall) parameter function for your `[Run]` entry, where you'll update the registry.

Comment: OK what I mean ? First I start silent installation of utility in RUN section. The utility write automatically entries in registry. After the installation of utility I need extra entries in registry for this utility. What can I do over Code ? Can you give me examples ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Examples are in help. If you would follow the link to `AfterInstall` parameter, you would already have your answer; you can do [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/measgGy4).

Comment: Hi TLama, It was........your last example. A lot of thanks for your help. :-)